# Comprehension's interaction with the enclosing scope?

Tags: python

I came across a passage in The Python Language Reference's section [6.2.4. Displays for lists, sets nad dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

> ...
>
> Subsequent `for` clauses and any filter condition in the leftmost for clause cannot be evaluated in the enclosing scope as they may depend on the values obtained from the leftmost iterable.
> ...

I thought it was relating to (preventing) the leakage of variables into the enclosing scope So I tried the following:

```py
>>> x = 42
>>> [x for a in range(3) if (x := a)]
[1, 2]
>>> x
2
```

The `(x := a)` is still affecting the enclosing scope. So it's probably not what I imagined.

Anyone knows what is the above passage alluding to?

---

## EDIT:

Just want to summarize my understanding to this, and share something funny.

### Summary:

How it works is that a comprehension will create it own symbol table to hold variables defined within the comprehension. This symbol table is discarded after we've done executing the comprehension. And because we have this temporary symbol table, the enclosing scope's symbol table will not be polluted by executing the comprehension. The exception is the assignment expression, which will connect to the enclosing enclosing scope. (See the answering post below.)

### Thoughts:

The above quoted passage got me confused because it says that it "cannot" be evaluated in the enclosing scope. I guess, language design-wise, there is no inherent reason that we "cannot" do it in that way, carrying out all the comprehension computation in the enclosing scope. The reason is just that the language designers decided to introduce a separate symbol table for each comprehension, and we might need to reference the symbols placed in the comprehension's symbol table.

### Funny Code:

Anyone knows why there is a `'.0'` in the comprehension's symbol table???

```py
>>> def foo():
...   x, y, z = 42, 43, 44
...   print([(outer, inner) for outer in locals() for inner in locals()])
... 
>>> foo()
[('x', '.0'), ('x', 'outer'), ('y', '.0'), ('y', 'outer'), ('y', 'inner'), ('z', '.0'), ('z', 'outer'), ('z', 'inner')]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a very specific exception for `:=`, not mentioned in the docs section you were reading. It should probably be mentioned *somewhere* on the page, but it's not in that section or in the [section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) for assignment expressions. If you read the [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) for assignment expressions, you'll find the exception mentioned under "[Scope of the target](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target)", but it's not reasonable to expect people to have to read that to find this information.

Anyway, `:=` in a comprehension or generator expression is specifically special-cased to assign the name in the enclosing scope, not the scope of the comprehension or generator expression. Loop variables don't receive this treatment, so if you were to try to print `a` from outside the comprehension, you would find no binding for `a`.

Comment: It should definitely be documented somewhere in the language reference. Otherwise, I can picture someone (probably me) writing something like `[a for x in nums_1 for y in nums_2 if (a := x + y)]` and thinking that `a` will not leak.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the assignment expression! But I guess I'm still a bit fuzzy about what the above quoted passage means. Is it just trying to say that the variables will not leak (except, of course, the assignment expression)?

Answer (score 0):

"For example: `[x*y for x in range(10) for y in range(x, x+10)]`."

`for y in range(x, x+10)` cannot be evaluated in the enclosing scope, because `x` is not defined in it. Instead, `x in range(10)` is evaluated and then a nested scope is created that does know what `x` is and now you can do `range(x, x+10)`.